# graphql-upload-minimal: how to destroy the stream when upload file size limit is reached?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

On a [Node.js](https://nodejs.dev/) [GraphQL API](https://graphql.org/), using [express](https://github.com/flash-oss/graphql-upload-minimal) + [@graphql-yoga/node](https://github.com/flash-oss/graphql-upload-minimal) + [graphql-upload-minimal](https://github.com/flash-oss/graphql-upload-minimal), I have the uploads working very well, but when I upload a huge file, and the upload file size limit is reached, the stream continues until be finished, and it imposes makes unnecessary waiting to finish the entire stream.

I tried the below code, but the 'reject' does't destroy the stream:

```
stream.on('limit', function () {
    const incomplete_file = `${folder}/${my_filename}`;
    fs.unlink(incomplete_file, function () {});
    reject(
      new GraphQLYogaError(`Error: Upload file size overflow`, {
        code: 'UPLOAD_SIZE_LIMIT_OVERFLOW',
      }),
    );
});
```

Full module below:

```
import getFilename from './getFilename';
import fs from 'fs';
import { GraphQLYogaError } from '@graphql-yoga/node';

export default async function uploadSingleFile(
  folder: string,
  file: any,
): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const { createReadStream, filename, fieldName, mimetype, encoding } =
      await file;
    const my_filename = getFilename(filename, fieldName);
    let size = 0;
    let stream = createReadStream();
    stream.on('data', function (chunk: any) {
      size += chunk.length;
      fs.appendFile(`${folder}/${my_filename}`, chunk, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
    });
    stream.on('close', function () {
      resolve({
        nameOriginal: filename,
        nameUploaded: my_filename,
        mimetype: mimetype,
      });
    });
    stream.on('limit', function () {
      const incomplete_file = `${folder}/${my_filename}`;
      fs.unlink(incomplete_file, function () {});
      reject(
        new GraphQLYogaError(`Error: Upload file size overflow`, {
          code: 'UPLOAD_SIZE_LIMIT_OVERFLOW',
        }),
      );
    });
  })
    .then((data) => data)
    .catch((e) => {
      throw new GraphQLYogaError(e.message);
    });
}
```

How I can force imediate end of stream? There is any method to destroy the stream?

Thanks for the help!